# POST method form in lxml raises TypeError with submit_form

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I'm trying to submit a POST method form using lxml and I'm getting a TypeError. This is a minimal example that raises this Error:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> page = lxml.html.parse("http://www.webcom.com/html/tutor/forms/start.shtml")
>>> form = page.getroot().forms[0]
>>> form.fields['your_name'] = 'Morphit'
>>> result = lxml.html.parse(lxml.html.submit_form(form))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
            File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 887, in submit_form
              return open_http(form.method, url, values)
            File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 907, in open_http_urllib
              return urlopen(url, data)
            File "/usr/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 160, in urlopen
              return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
            File "/usr/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 471, in open
              req = meth(req)
            File "/usr/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1183, in do_request_
              raise TypeError(msg)
          TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

I've found the exact error elsewhere online, but I haven't seen it generated from inside lxml like this. Does anyone know if this is a bug, or expected behaviour and how to work around it?

Comment: I have the same bug.. it really seems like a bug because it's internal management of str/unicode/bytes.

Comment: For reference, Morphit submitted a bug to [lxml's bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1074996), [proposed a pull request](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/122) to fix the patch, even improved it based on feedback. Sadly, the pull request is still waiting to be merged!

Comment: @Morphit: You could add your proposed pull request as an answer here. Accept that answer, so that this is no longer an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/122/files:

"In python3, urlopen expects a byte stream for the POST data. this patch encodes the data in utf-8 before transmission." In src/lxml/html/__init__.py, change line 918,

```
data = urlencode(values)
```

to

```
data = urlencode(values).encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is Python 3, so you should write

```
form.fields['your_name'] = b'Morphit'
```

or

```
form.fields['your_name'] = 'Morphit'.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: field values do not matter. Try `python3 -c 'import lxml.html; lxml.html.submit_form(lxml.html.fromstring("""<form method=POST action="http://doesnot.matter"></form>""").forms[0])'`

Answer (score 0):

```
def myopen_http(method, url, values):
   if not url:
      raise ValueError("cannot submit, no URL provided")
   ## FIXME: should test that it's not a relative URL or something
   try:
      from urllib import urlencode, urlopen
   except ImportError: # Python 3
      from urllib.request import urlopen
      from urllib.parse import urlencode
   if method == 'GET':
      if '?' in url:
         url += '&'
      else:
         url += '?'
         url += urlencode(values)
         data = None
   else:
      data = urlencode(values).encode('utf-8')

   return urlopen(url, data)

result = lxml.html.parse(lxml.html.submit_form(form, open_http=myopen_http))
```